# Microsoft.Graph API expand method doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

What I am trying to do is retrieve all users with their managers data

```
await _client.Users.Request().Select("email, displayname, manager")
      .Top(5).Expand(x => x.Manager).GetAsync()
```

Yet, result is always null (tried few different variations). Does Microsoft.Graph API supports this functionality? Because I've tried same requests through Microsoft.Graph and Azure AD Graph Explorers and only azure one returned manager data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/77) :

> > The manager property is a navigation property on a user so you'll have to request that property value for each user.

So currently Microsoft Graph SDK doesn't support retrieving all users with their managers data . You may use Azure AD Graph API as a workaround(`https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/users/?$expand=manager&api-version=2013-11-08`). If you want microsoft graph api supports that feature , you can send a feedback in [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) .

Comment: I've found on their main site, that they don't fully support expand function, so went to the same conclusion as you. Still thanks for proving my idea